# How to use web service as data source on Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to use a web service as a data source in the Pentaho report designer.

Can you please guide me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have Pentaho Data Integration, you can do it the hard way with Groovy scripting, I have an example here (although it uses a Java client not a Web client):

http://funpdi.blogspot.com/2014/09/groovy-datasources-with-pentaho-report.html

With Pentaho Data Integration, you can create a transformation that uses a REST step to get data from a web service. Then in Pentaho Report Designer you can create a Pentaho Data Integration datasource, choose the step you want to get fields from, then use those fields in your report. There's a great blog post explaining this process:

http://infochick76.blogspot.com/2013/10/pentaho-report-integration-with-web.html